# Characters limit in SMS for iOS

Tags: iphone, sms, limit

I want to send large inforamtion via SMS in my app around 2000 chars. I am just curious to know the Characters limit in SMS for iOS. Any one know about this? Hwo iOS will handle this?

Comment: I hope the character limit is set by the operator and not by the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMS limit isn't by the OS, but by the provider. UTF8 messages are usually 70 chars, GSM 7-bit is limited to 140/160 depends on provider. Longer messages are broken into parts.

Answer (score 2):

SMS content is usually limited to 1120 bit by the provider (= 160 characters for the most common enconding). For longer messages, the content is normally divided into several SMS.

Comment: Thanks for info. So that means as a developer we don't need to worry about sms size , right?